# Concat a xml node with a variable in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, path, concatenation

Hi I need to concat a xsl node path with a variable to have a dinamic node path in xslt.

I have this node:

```
<PRODOTTI>
  <ITEM STATO="2">
</PRODOTTI>
<STATI>
  <COD0>Errore</COD0>
  <COD1>In spedizione entro le prossime 12-24 ore</COD1>
  <COD2>In spedizione entro le prossime 24-48 ore</COD2>
 </STATI>
```

and in xsl I have

```
<xsl:variable name="stato_ordine" select="@STATO"/>
<xsl:variable name="ordine" select="concat(../../../TRADUZIONI/STATI/COD, $stato_ordine)" />
<xsl:value-of select="$ordine"></xsl:value-of>
```

but in output I only get the "stato_ordine" value, instead i'd need the complete path to get the node value.

Is there anyway to have this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `../../../TRADUZIONI/STATI/COD` is selecting the right thing? Could you try `//STATI/COD` instead, just as a test?

Comment: I tried, unfortunately same results

Comment: And if you just output the value of `//STATI/COD`, do you get the expected results?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `<xsl:value-of select="../../../TRADUZIONI/STATI/*[local-name() = concat('COD', $stato_ordine)]"/>`.

[edit]
For a more efficient solution you could define a key as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="STATI/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'COD')]" use="substring(local-name(), 4)"/>
```

and then doing

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $stato_ordine)"/>
```

should suffice.